# How to use vbNewLine in RegExp with Visual Basic

Tags: regex, vbscript

I have a problem regarding the deletion of extensively used vbNewLine's in arbitrary text with Visual Basic.

What I want basically is: When there are more then two vbNewLine after another delete all but the first two of them.

For Example:

```
This is some sample text.

It contains a lot of new lines.



Too much in fact.
```

Should boil down to:

```
This is some sample text.

It contains a lot of new lines.

Too much in fact.
```

Code Example:

```
Dim testText : testText = "This is some sample text." & vbNewLine &  vbNewLine & "It contains a lot of new lines." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Too much in fact."

Dim objRegExp
Set objRegExp = New RegExp

objRegExp.Pattern = "" & "vbNewLine" & "{2,}"
'objRegExp.Pattern = "" & "vbNewLine" -> Works for single vbNewLine's
'objRegExp.Pattern = "" & "vbNewLine" -> Works for multiple instances of a (aa, aaa, aaaa, etc.)

Dim result : result = objRegExp.Replace(testText, vbNewLine)
```

However my pattern seems to be wrong. If I use "" & "vbNewLine" as pattern, I can replace each single newline. And when I use "a{2,}" I can replace any number of a's >= 2 which is exactly what I want, but for vbNewLines. However the code above does not work. Any suggestions on how to proceed? Using "\r\n" has not yet helped me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following expression:

```
(\r?\n)(?:\r?\n){2,}
```

and replace with `$1$1`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XrqxIL/1).

In code:

```
objRegExp.Pattern = "(\r?\n)(?:\r?\n){2,}"
objRegExp.Global = True
```

and then

```
Dim result : result = objRegExp.Replace(testText, "$1$1")
```

The `Global` should be *True* to replace all non-overlapping instances.

**Pattern details**:

- `(\r?\n)` - Capturing group 1 matching an optional *vbCr* and then a *vbLf*
- `(?:\r?\n){2,}` - 2 or more sequences of the pattern used in Group 1.

The `$1` is a backreference to the line break captured within Group 1.

If you want to hard code the line break, use `vbCrLf & vbCrLf` in the replacement. Or any other line break style you need.

Comment: Incredibly fast awnser. Works like a charm. Thanks allot!